# PIL - Images not rotating

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm curious as to why my image is not rotating, it ends up in the same position every time.

```
img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Brett\Downloads\testing.jpg')
exif_data = {
    TAGS[k]: v
    for k, v in img._getexif().items()
    if k in TAGS
}
print(exif_data['Orientation'])
```

That outputs a '6'

No matter how many degrees I tell the image to rotate it ends up in the same position.

```
if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
    img.rotate(90)
```

or

```
if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
    img.rotate(270)
```

or

```
if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
    img.rotate(180)
```

I always end up with an image rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Did you save the rotated image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the ([DOCS](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate))

> Image.rotate(angle, resample=0, expand=0, center=None, translate=None)
>
> Returns a rotated copy of this image. This method returns a copy of this image, rotated the given number of degrees counter clockwise around its centre.

The image is not rotated in place.  You need to store the image returned from `rotate()`.  Maybe something like:

```
if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
    new_image = img.rotate(180)
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense for it to be that way.

Comment: Yes but, the verb `rotate` sounds like it might be in place.  Maybe they should have called it `rotated`?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggested answer above you could also just do the following.

```
if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
    img = img.rotate(90)
```

or

```
if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
    img = img.rotate(270)
```

or

```
if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
    img = img.rotate(180)
```

Additionally as mentioned above you may want to set the expand parameter, like the following to ensure that you don't run out of canvas for the rotated image.

```
if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
    img.rotate(180,expand=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: If you rotate the image you should also modify the exif:

```
from PIL import Image
from exif import Image as Image2


def check_rotation(how, rotat):
    if "must be horizontal":
        if rotat == 6:
            return 1
        elif rotat == 8:
            return 3
        return None
    elif "must be vertical":
        if rotat == 3:                
            return 6
        elif rotat == 1:
            return 8
        return None
    else:
        raise "wrong how"

with Image.open(old_file, "r") as im:
    try:
        rotation = im._getexif()[274]
    except:
        raise "Failed to load exif with PIL"

    result = check_rotation("must be vertical", rotation)
    if result:
        print("rotated")
        # this ment the image must be rotated by 90 degrees and the exif_rotation will be updated by what the function returns
        im.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)
        rotation = result  
    im.save(fp=f"{new_file}.jpg", format="JPEG", exif=im.info['exif'], quality=90)
    # here you see that it actually didn't rotate yet

with open(f"{new_file}.jpg", "rb") as im_file:
    imexif = Image2(im_file)
    if imexif.has_exif:
        # Updating exif rotation
        if imexif.get("orientation"):
            try:
                imexif.orientation = rotation
                # now it will rotate
            except:
                print("failed to modify EXIF orientation")
    # Writing the EXIF
    with open(f"{new_file}.jpg", 'wb') as updated_file:
        updated_file.write(imexif.get_file())
```